# Count unique integer value between multiple overlapping ranges saved in mysql table + PHP

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.4

We have a situation to get unique count between saved range of mysql table. lets say, I have data saved in table like below:

| sr_no | start_sr_no | end_sr_number | total_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 5 | 15 | 11 |
| 3 | 27 | 35 | 9 |
| 4 | 11 | 21 | 11 |

now see in above records, row sr_no 2 is overlapping the row sr_no 1 and row sr_no 4 so the unique total_count of all 3 range should be: 21 instead of 10+11+11 = 32 and all range total count should be:30 instead of 10+11+9+11:41

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: *hope i am clear with what i am trying to achieve.* You tell nothing about this. Show desired query output for shown data.

Comment: 10.4.17-MariaDB

Comment: @Akina that table already has the total records for range_from and range_to so what query you are looking for?

Comment: Do you mean that shown table is an output of your query, and you want to join the ranges on PHP side, not in the query?

Comment: @Akina rows 1,2, & 4 overlap. So the total would be 21-1(+1). This seems straightforward.

Comment: That is saved in table, not output.. i want unique total_count for integers.

Answer (score 1):

> 10.4.17-MariaDB – Rakesh Verma

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT start_sr_no value, 1 weight FROM test
          UNION ALL
          SELECT end_sr_number, -1 FROM test ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *,
                 SUM(weight) OVER (ORDER BY value, weight DESC) cost
          FROM cte1 ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT value, 
                 SUM(cost = 0) OVER (ORDER BY value DESC) grp
          FROM cte2 )
SELECT MIN(value) start_sr_no, 
       MAX(value) end_sr_number, 
       MAX(value) - MIN(value) + 1 total_count
FROM cte3
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY 1
```

For total values only use

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT start_sr_no value, 1 weight FROM test
          UNION ALL
          SELECT end_sr_number, -1 FROM test ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *,
                 SUM(weight) OVER (ORDER BY value, weight DESC) cost
          FROM cte1 ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT value, 
                 SUM(cost = 0) OVER (ORDER BY value DESC) grp
          FROM cte2 ),
cte4 AS ( SELECT MIN(value) start_sr_no, 
                 MAX(value) end_sr_number, 
                 MAX(value) - MIN(value) + 1 total_count
          FROM cte3
          GROUP BY grp )
SELECT SUM(total_count) total_count
FROM cte4
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=a627f3276bf2fd60d6bcfc986d4c19d9

---

> needed same query for lower versions of mysql as well such as MySQL5.5 – Rakesh Verma

```sql
SELECT MIN(start) start_sr_no,
       MAX(finish) end_sr_number,
       MAX(finish) - MIN(start) + 1 total_count
FROM ( SELECT CASE WHEN start_sr_no > @prev_finish
            THEN @group := @group + 1
                   ELSE @group
                   END grp,
              CASE WHEN start_sr_no BETWEEN @prev_start AND @prev_finish
                   THEN @prev_start
                   ELSE @prev_start := start_sr_no
                   END start, 
              CASE WHEN end_sr_number < @prev_finish
                   THEN @prev_finish
                   ELSE @prev_finish := end_sr_number
                   END finish
       FROM test
       CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @prev_start := -1,
                           @prev_finish := -1,
                           @group := 0 ) init_variables
       ORDER BY start_sr_no, end_sr_number ) enumerated
GROUP BY grp
```

and

```sql
SELECT SUM(total_count) total_count
FROM ( SELECT MIN(start) start_sr_no,
              MAX(finish) end_sr_number,
              MAX(finish) - MIN(start) + 1 total_count
       FROM ( SELECT CASE WHEN start_sr_no > @prev_finish
                   THEN @group := @group + 1
                          ELSE @group
                          END grp,
                     CASE WHEN start_sr_no BETWEEN @prev_start AND @prev_finish
                          THEN @prev_start
                          ELSE @prev_start := start_sr_no
                          END start, 
                     CASE WHEN end_sr_number < @prev_finish
                          THEN @prev_finish
                   ELSE @prev_finish := end_sr_number
                   END finish
                   FROM test
              CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @prev_start := -1,
                                  @prev_finish := -1,
                                  @group := 0 ) init_variables
              ORDER BY start_sr_no, end_sr_number ) enumerated
       GROUP BY grp ) total
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=e2e3e6a6bd00aca2f8c53de50638788d

Comment: hi, thnx.. seems pretty interesting but what if we have more than 4 record in the table?

Comment: @RakeshVerma Test, what a problem?

Comment: hi, needed same query for lowler versions of mysql as well such as MySQL5.5 .. with command is not working.. tried with temporary tables as well.. but no luck.

Comment: @RakeshVerma Added.

Comment: You are rock bro.. :)